# iPhone app release date and new section questions

Tags: iphone, date, app-store, release

I read that if you set your app's release date to a future date and it gets approved, the approval date is counted as the release date. So, if you are set to a future date, you wont appear in the "new" section and lose viewership.

I also read that after your app is put in the appstore, you can change the date to a past or equal date to change the "release date". So on the day your app is released, you can reset the release date from the approval day, to any past or equal day to the present. This would get you **rightfully** on to the new section and make you not miss your viewership in the "new" section. **But, the article that said this is old and not-updated.**

Here it is: http://www.dragthing.com/blog/2008/10/how-to-change-your-app-store-release-date/ (2008)

**So, does this trick still work?** Or was it removed because of exploitation? Because my app release date is in the past, and I  don't want to miss my only guaranteed viewership I will ever get.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your app's release date is the date that you set in the store. Once the app is released, you can not change it.

If you set your app farther in the future, it's approval date will **NOT** become the release date.

If you set your app's release date and it isn't approved before the release date the release date does NOT become the approval date. You want to watch out for this, because it has implications for whether or not your app shows up in the "what's new" category.

This is my experience anyway.

Comment: This was not the case for me. Mine was approved on the 17th even though my release date was set later, and now it has become the "release date." Will this change after my app really hits the stores?